# How to redirect into different page by user type in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, usertype

I want to redirect the users from the same log-in page.

folder structure...

```
root
|
--------/application/app.php <---------- for normal user
|
--------/administration/admin.php <------- for admin user
|
-------- index.php (Log-in page)
```

User Table

```
ID       USER_NAME       PASSWORD      USER_TYPE
1         admin           pass@admin    admin
2         user            pass@user     user
```

If the login user's user type is admin then he/she will be redirected to `/administration/admin.php` else `/application/app.php`.

How can I do it ?

Regards,

Comment: Just read what user_type the user is and set a header location if statement for each one?

Comment: search in google PHP redirect.

Comment: @AndyHolmes thank you for reply. I should tell you first, I am new in php. So i need some code samples.

Comment: @Raj please see my answer for help

Comment: @Raj could you review my answer and provide feedback? :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes Let me try first. I will definitely give you feedback.

Comment: @AndyHolmes One more thing. One of my friends told me about session variables and it can be implemented in log-in page to serve my need. How ?

Comment: @Raj that's a completely different question and you didn't outline it before. Go with this first, then then look at sessions after :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes I tried but it showing the blank page.

Comment: @Raj Did it try redirecting? What's in your address bar? Have you actually selected it from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the username and password. You can check their usertype and save it to a variable in this case **$user_type**.

$user_type = $row['user_type']   //get the usertype of the user from table row in your database

```
if( $user == 1){ //check if user or password is correct from query


 if($user_type == "normal user"){ //check usertype

    header("Location:/application/app.php"); //if normal user redirect to app.php

    }else{

    header("Location:/administration/admin.php"); //if admin user redirect to admin.php

    }
}
```

Comment: At least use the `user_type` OP has outlined

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$userType = $row['user_type'];

if($userType == 'admin'){
    header("Location: /administration/admin.php"); // This line triggers a redirect if the user_type is admin
} else {
    header("Location: /application/app.php"); // This line triggers for other user_types
}

?>
```

`$row['user_type'];` is simulating your `SELECT` from your database, I won't write the connection script for you, but this is just a guideline into what you need to look into. Also, look into PDO or MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated.

Comment: Downvoter, would you kindly comment as to why you have downvoted this?