# php- redirection works on only one page

Tags: php

so I tried using the code from Andy Holmes from this link [How to redirect into different page by user type in php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881616/how-to-redirect-into-different-page-by-user-type-in-php-and-mysql).

Server.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
  $occupation = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['occupation']);
  $grdlvl = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['grdlvl']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }
  if (empty($occupation)) { array_push($errors, "Occupation is required"); }
  if (empty($grdlvl)) { array_push($errors, "Grade level Applied is required"); }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, occupation, grdlvl) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', '$occupation', '$grdlvl')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now registered";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
}

// ... 

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
}
$occupation = $row['$occupation'];

if($occupation == "student"){ //check usertype

    header("Location:/site2/student.php"); //if normal user redirect to app.php

    }else{

    header("Location:/site2/admin.php"); //if admin user redirect to admin.php
     }
}

    else {
      array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }

?>
```

But the problem is it works for only one page and It keeps redirecting to the admin page even if the occupation is not admin.

Comment: Unless occupation equals student, it redirects to admin and `$occupation = $row['$occupation']`. However, I don't see you set the value of `$row` anywhere. So, the redirect will always be to admin.

Comment: thanks you so much for the comment. I've been dealing with this badly and your insight helped

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. I guess I should add it as an answer so that others looking at this question find it more easily. Feel free to accept it and edit it with any of your findings.

Comment: yes please do. I have already incorporated it, truly thanks for the help

Comment: and including another code helped make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless occupation equals student, it redirects to admin and `$occupation = $row['$occupation']`. However, I don't see you set the value of `$row` anywhere. So, the redirect will always be to admin.